# Android - Open/Close a drawer with more than just a ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I want to open/close a drawer by code when pressing the action bar home button, so I did the following in onOptionsItemSelected:

```
case android.R.id.home:
    if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerListView)) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    return true;
```

The problem is, my drawer is not just a ListView but:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mainPhoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:layout_height="128dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvOptions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:dividerHeight="3dp"
        android:background="#cccc" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and in activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="com.example.example.DrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/drawer_fragment" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

So when the code above executes, it gives me a casting error: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams

I tried to give an id to the LinearLayout and use that but it didn't help or maybe I did something wrong... please advice

Comment: Please provide onCreate code where you use `findViewById`, I think it is your issue

Comment: mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); and mDrawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvOptions);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking if the `drawer` is open with `gravity` works for me instead of checingk for the `view`. This is my code:

```
public void openMenu(int gravity){
    if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(gravity))
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(gravity);
    else
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(gravity);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your way and it works but I wonder if I miss something by not using the other "version" of isDrawerOpen and open/closeDrawer? The other version works only for ListView only drawers?

Comment: No, it's supposed to work with any view you inflated in the drawer. Maybe you could have missed some `findViewById()` ? Glad to help :)

Comment: I meant what is the purpose of mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerListView) over the  GravityCompat.START version? Except for the fact it's probably works only on a ListView drawer :)

Comment: I guess it could be useful when you have multiple drawers and you don't want to worry about each one's position, so you'd deal only with the views you already know.